# PermissionError : cannot access the file because it is being used by another process, even when admin

Tags: conda, python-newspaper

I'm trying to install [a library named newspaper](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/newspaper3k). Yet I had issues of permissions errors as it seemed another process was used a package which was being uninstalled : package 'defaults::qt-5.9.6-vc14h1e9a669_2'.

```
(base) C:\Users\antoi>conda install -c conda-forge newspaper3k
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##
 ...

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::qt-5.9.6-vc14h1e9a669_2'.
PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process')
```

I launched the Annaconda command terminal as an Administrator but it didn't worked either.

Comment: I had this problem today. Silly me, solved it by quitting Spyder

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because qt is being used by your Anaconda Navigator, I have had the same problem, it can be solved by various means reaching the same end.

You can run your Anaconda Navigator, switch to your environment -if you are using default do not switch- then run console through the Environments menu, close Anaconda Navigator, install your package.

You can run your Anaconda Console directly, switch to your environment and install your package.

These two ways should work, first one is a confirmed solution.

Comment: i had Spyder running even after closing Anaconda, and worked for me after closing Spyder as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by installing the package with pip rather than conda.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21558309)

Comment: @bobbyrne01, This is not a thank you, it's an anwser : install the package with pip rather than conda. Furthermore I asked the question, it would be weird to thanks myself

Comment: It doesn't really read like an answer. You may want to consider explicitly describing the steps involved and reduce the 'conversational' tone.